# cant get api array to output 1 first element from array, it only outputs all elements at once in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, api

i cant get array to only output one element, it only out puts all elements at once when you enter a value in the box, this is the api im using https://market.mashape.com/community/urban-dictionary

I tried playing around with the jquery but i cant get it to output only 1 element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#submit').click(function() {
    var wat = $('#wat').val();
    $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "https://mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.mashape.com/define?term=wat",
      // data: { fragment: false, json: true },        https://market.mashape.com/montanaflynn/gender-guesser
      data: {
        wat: wat
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data.list);
        $(data.list).each(function(key, value) {
          document.write(value.definition)
          console.log(key);
          console.log(value);
          console.log(value.definition)

          $("#response").append(value.definition);

        });
        // Place the 10 def into yuor response div
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
      },
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Mashape-Key', '7OByASqCq9msh5cE6uU43zz9HxOwp1kzb1ajsn26OZDiaXH06E');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        // xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://montanaflynn-gender-guesser.p.mashape.com/?name=Aaron ' );
        // xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
        // xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');                    
      }

    });

  });

});
```

```html
<h1>Facts</h1>
<input type="text" name="wat" id="wat">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Get a Fact" id="submit">
<div id="response">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

it gives me all the elements from the array instead of one

Comment: output any element i mean, not just the first element

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. The API call returns an array which you can access by index if you just want one element from it. Also, remove `document.write`. It's bad practice to use and it's messing up your output.

Comment: there are 10 elements in the array, i want to print out only 1, right now it is printing out all the 10 elements at once

Comment: Remove the `$.each` call and use `$('#response').append(data.list.definition[0]);` instead

Comment: try to access by key array [0], look my answer @Dannixx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want only the first element need to acces by key array  `data.list[0]`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#submit').click(function() {
    var wat = $('#wat').val();
    $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "https://mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.mashape.com/define?term=wat",
      // data: { fragment: false, json: true },        https://market.mashape.com/montanaflynn/gender-guesser
      data: {
        wat: wat
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data.list[0]);
       //$(data.list).each(function(key, value) {
          //document.write(value.definition)
         // console.log(key);
          //console.log(value);
         // console.log(value.definition)

          $("#response").append(data.list[0].definition);

        //});
        // Place the 10 def into yuor response div
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
      },
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Mashape-Key', '7OByASqCq9msh5cE6uU43zz9HxOwp1kzb1ajsn26OZDiaXH06E');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        // xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://montanaflynn-gender-guesser.p.mashape.com/?name=Aaron ' );
        // xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
        // xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');                    
      }

    });

  });

});
```

```html
<h1>Facts</h1>
<input type="text" name="wat" id="wat">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Get a Fact" id="submit">
<div id="response">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```